# What is the easiest way to back up an assistant project created with the "Actions Console" web version?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am happy with how easy the "action console" can be used in the Chrome Browser. Out of curiosity i also installed the CLI-option on my Ubuntu system and played a bit around with it.

The difference here is obvious that with the CLI you always have your project on your own system.
Does this mean that a "pull" command via the CLI the easiest way to backup a Project created with the "Actions Console" in the web-browser?
Or does anyone know of any plans in adding something like a "download project as zip" in the Actions Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to backup Actions Builder projects is to use the [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions). The `pull` command will download all project files, allowing you to modify your project offline and locally.

You can then `push` the local files back to the same project to update your action.

When you have downloaded all the files, you can then further back them up in whatever mechanism you'd prefer. This could be bundling everything into a `.zip` file or using a version control system like git.

Comment: In theory i understand that but it feels like having to choose between the blue or the red wire of the bomb :D
What i mean: As there is no undo-history in the Actions Console i am totally afraid of mixing up pull and push when doing the backup.
Today i caught myself in closing a few tabs of my intents, just when i realized that i was NOT closing them but hitting the trash button :D

Comment: Yeah I understand it can potentially trip you up, but you may be able to use these lower-level APIs to create an automatic backup utility for greater peace of mind.